# fast scroll RecyclerView,the ToggleButton in item will wrong

Tags: android

there is a `ToggleButton` in my `RecyclerView` item.so , all the ToggleButton is unChecked. But when I fast scroll RecyclerView form bottom to top,the list will move to circle...after with time-lapse photography , I found that one of the item's ToggleButton was checked! it's weird...
code is here,I don't think there is some problem...
this is the holder..

```
public class CommentsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView dateTextView;
TextView contentTextView;
ImageView iconImageView;
ToggleButton hideToggleButton;

View viewBorder;
View lastViewBorder;


public CommentsHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
    contentTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentTextView);
    iconImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
    hideToggleButton = (ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hideToggleButton);
    viewBorder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewBorder);
    lastViewBorder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastViewBorder);
}

public void setData(final StoryDetail.Format story, int icon, boolean isLastItem) {
    String strDate = CommonFunction.genTimeString(story.comment.getCreateDate());
    dateTextView.setText(strDate);
    iconImageView.setImageResource(icon);
    contentTextView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    contentTextView.setText(story.comment.getContent());
    if (isLastItem) {
        viewBorder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lastViewBorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewBorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lastViewBorder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    contentTextView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (contentTextView.getLineCount() <= 3) {
                hideToggleButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                hideToggleButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (story.comment.isShowAll()) {
                contentTextView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            } else {
                contentTextView.setMaxLines(3);
            }
        }
    });
    hideToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    hideToggleButton.setChecked(story.comment.isShowAll());
    hideToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                contentTextView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            } else {
                contentTextView.setMaxLines(3);
            }
            story.comment.setShowAll(isChecked);
        }
    });
}
```

this is adapter:

```
class StoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch (viewType) {
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.HEADER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_header_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.TEXT:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_text_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TextViewHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.IMAGE:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_image_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ImageViewHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.FROM_GRANDPA:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_grandpa_letter_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new GrandpaLetterHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.FROM_USER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_user_letter_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new UserLetterHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_TITLE:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_comment_title_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new CommentTitleHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_PLACE_HOLDER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_place_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new PlaceHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENT_HEADER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_rcommend_comment_header_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ReCommentHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENTS:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_comments_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new CommentsHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_HEADER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_comment_header_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new CommentHeaderHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENTS:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_comments_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new CommentsHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.TIP:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_tip_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TipHolder(itemView);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        Log.e("position-----------", position + "");
        switch (viewType) {
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.HEADER:
                HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
                headerViewHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));

                boolean hideSubmission =
                        TYPE_NAME_MAIL_FROM_GRANDPA.equals(storyDetail.formats.get(position).title.subtitle) ||
                                TYPE_NAME_BULLETIN.equals(storyDetail.formats.get(position).title.subtitle) ||
                                TYPE_ID_BULLETIN.equals(storyDetail.formats.get(position).title._id) ||
                                TYPE_ID_MAIL_FROM_GRANDPA.equals(storyDetail.formats.get(position).title._id);

                setSubmissionButtonState(!hideSubmission);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.TEXT:
                TextViewHolder textViewHolder = (TextViewHolder) holder;
                textViewHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.IMAGE:
                ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) holder;
                imageViewHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.FROM_GRANDPA:
                GrandpaLetterHolder grandpaLetterHolder = (GrandpaLetterHolder) holder;
                grandpaLetterHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.FROM_USER:
                UserLetterHolder userLetterHolder = (UserLetterHolder) holder;
                userLetterHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_TITLE:
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_PLACE_HOLDER:
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENT_HEADER:
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENTS:
                Log.e("position", position + "");
                CommentsHolder commentsHolder = (CommentsHolder) holder;
                commentsHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position), R.mipmap.story_comment_icon_brown,
                        position + 1 < getItemCount() && storyDetail.formats.get(position + 1).type != StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENTS);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_HEADER:
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENTS:
                CommentsHolder commentsHolder1 = (CommentsHolder) holder;
                commentsHolder1.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position), R.mipmap.story_comment_mine_icon_black, false);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.TIP:
                TipHolder tipHolder = (TipHolder) holder;
                tipHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (storyDetail == null || storyDetail.formats == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return storyDetail.formats.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        super.getItemViewType(position);
        return storyDetail.formats.get(position).type;
    }
}
```

please help me . thanks a lot~

Comment: you can  put a log for story.comment.isShowAll() to check in which condition your its getting true

Comment: actually,I know which item will be check.but it's not always in the same position....

Comment: okk .. in onBindViewHolder method if you are setting checked to toggleButton in any if condition then in else condition you must uncheck it

Comment: well,I'll try it,thank u~

Comment: @yibozhange okk let me know if it works for you

Comment: it's so weird....I log isShowAll(),all log is false.....so I have no idea of why ....

Comment: check in the xml if by default ToggleButton is set checked or not

Comment: it seems every thing is ok , so I think If it's recyclerView's problem?

Comment: no this can't be happen in any case ... recycler view just recycle its views that are not in used currently. You must check your conditions where you set toogleButton checked to true.. and don't forget to uncheck it in other statement

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreateViewholder you need to set the tags for every ViewHolder that you create and before you should check if there is a view holder that exists with that tag then only you go and create the the new one other wise you use the already existing one this would solve your problem of corrupted views.

something like below

```
  @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder;

        //setting the tags to the viewholder to avoid duplicate views when recycling
        if (view.getTag() == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        return holder;
    }
```